# How to convert from Expression to CriteriaBuilder in JPA

Tags: java, spring, jpa, expression, criteria

I have below code which uses outdated `Expression`

```
Criteria criteria = getSession().createCriteria(TagSynonym.class);
criteria.add(Expression.like("title", "%"+piece+"%") );
criteria.setFirstResult(0);
criteria.setMaxResults(maxTagsInResult);
return criteria.list();
```

I want to achieve same with `CriteriaBuilder`. Below is what I tried, however it returns an empty array. Please guide what do I miss here. Also guide how to set limit on result.

```
EntityManager em = this.getEntityManager();
CriteriaBuilder criteriaBuilder = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
CriteriaQuery<TagSynonym> query = criteriaBuilder.createQuery(TagSynonym.class);

Root<TagSynonym> fromTagsSynonyms = query.from(TagSynonym.class);
Predicate likesTags = criteriaBuilder.equal(fromTagsSynonyms.get(TagSynonym_.title), "%"+piece+"%");
query.select(fromTagsSynonyms).where(likesTags);
return em.createQuery(query).getResultList();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use [`CriteriaBuilder#like()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/criteria/CriteriaBuilder.html#like(javax.persistence.criteria.Expression,%20java.lang.String)) instead of `CriteriaBuilder#equal()`, to perform `like` matching.

```java
Predicate likesTags = criteriaBuilder.like(fromTagsSynonyms.get(TagSynonym_.title), "%"+piece+"%");
```

For the rest your code is basically correct.